# "General system exception happened" always while importing product csb magento2

Tags: magento2

Magento2 shows "General system exception happened" always while i am importing CSV, while some time before its gets accepted by magneto. Currently some product attribute incresed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to save the CSV with open office by checking option of quote every field with double inverted commas. This helped me to solve this. Hope will solve your problem as well.